# How to set Data source within Table Model file In Cake 3 ?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cake 2 I could  set it with this $this->setDataSource('database_name'); and create property of the same name in the Config\database.php

In CakePHP 3 I have added an additional Datasource in app.php after default but unable to use $this->setDataSource( within the initialize. I get Unknown method "setDatasource".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CakePHP 3.x, datasources are "connections". You can set the connection [on a table](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_setConnection) like so:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$table = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$table->setConnection($connection);
```

If you want the table to always use a different connection, you can use the `initialize` hook to set it.

You can also [set the connection for a specific query](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_setConnection).